# Using a npm package inside a NodeJS module

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to use googleapis npm package in my module but I am getting following error:

```
var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
                       ^

TypeError: google.gmail is not a function
    at Object.watchInbox (/home/ubuntu/workspace/functions/google_cloud.js:19:24)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/bootstrap.js:54:38
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:446:3)
```

Here is the module code:

(google_cloud.js)

```
const google = require('googleapis');

/**
 * Watch the Gmail Inbox
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function watchInbox(auth) {
  ..
  var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
  gmail.users.watch(options, function (err, response) {
    ..
  }
  ..
}


module.exports = {
  watchInbox
}
```

Here is the parent file  code:

(index.js)

```
var googleCloudModules = require("./functions/google_cloud.js");
..    
googleCloudModules.watchInbox(auth)
..
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: const {google} = require('googleapis'); will work

Comment: @VictorOliveira thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
```

This fixed it!